# Possible to us TLS on many autonomously created VPSs?

Tags: security, proxy, dns, vps, tls1.2

Is there any autonomous/programmatic way to create many VPS/cloud servers that securely serve a web page that will be accepted by off-the-shelf browsers without buying a new domain name for every VPS? I'm trying to find a solution that is fast, secure, and completely autonomous and it totally stumps me.

Creating many servers programmatically is easy--eg. create DigitalOcean droplets with their API.  I also understand how to programmatically setup a web server and secure it with TLS using Let's Encrypt. The part that stumps me is how to setup TLS autonomously for an arbitrary number of VPSs.
[image]
**What I've tried/though of so far:**

1. Self-signed cert for the IP address of the new VPS won't be accepted by browsers without warnings of plague and death
2. Let's Encrypt does not support bare IP addresses, only domain names and I can't find any provider that offers bare IP certs with automated and cheap verification
3. I could buy a wildcard cert and create a new (random?) subdomain for every VPS but then it could take hours for the DNS records to propagate to my end user
4. I could setup ahead of time a few hundred subdomains, point IP addresses to them and then secure them with a wildcard cert but that would be really expensive, like $4/month per IP address to reserve it
5. I could use something like DigitalOcean's floating IPs and assign them to the VPS as it's created but again, that costs $4/month to reserve each floating IP
6. I could use a wildcard cert with pre-setup subdomains that are pointed to by a DDNS and update the DDNS when the new VPS is created. But again, as far as I understand DDNS, it could take hours or at least minutes for the propagation.
7. I could only secure one server with TLS then proxy traffic from the outside world through that server and then to the VPSs using self-signed certs. This would probably work but add latency and a performance bottleneck. The application is already needing high performance and low latency so this is not attractive.

Is there something I haven't thought of? Anyone with out of the box ideas?
Any DNS or DDNS gurus out there who know how to instantly assign a new subdomain to a new IP address? Can you avoid caching delays with random subdomains? Any cert authorities who issue automated bare IP address certs?

Thank you!

***Background:*** My client sells a piece of software that runs only on Linux and they want to enable their customers to user that software occasionally in the cloud from any browser. My plan is to program a cloud hypervisor that serves a web interface, takes a request from the customer to use the software, spins up a new DigitalOcean droplet with an image that runs the software, connects the customer's browser to a VNC-to-websocket proxy, then destroys the droplet when the session is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate the infrastructure give a try to [terraform](https://www.terraform.io) for now probably is the most consistent and "easy" way of creating all your instances.

Now for using TLS on all your domain/subdomain probably the easiest solution is to delegate this to [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) (considering you app is a web page HTTP/HTTPS):

> Cloudflare-issued SSL certificates cover the root-level domain (eg- example.com) and one level of subdomains (eg- *.example.com)

In case you need to get the certificate and later use it like for a local web instance or an SMTP server you can still use [lestencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) but do the [verification via DNS](https://nbari.com/post/letsencrypt-cloudfare/),  this way, you don't need a web server and can "programmatically" manage your certificates, the how you deploy them or put them in your instances is another topic, maybe for that "[ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)" could help to automate that process.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but I can't understand how that helps. I understand I can get wildcard certs (what you're describing from Cloudlare). This doesn't solve the problem of having a new VPS with a new IP address. The only way to secure it (that I know of) is to create a new DNS A record pointing a subdomain to the new IP address. This can take hours to propagate and my customers don't want to wait hours to use on-demand software.

Comment: the DNS from CloudFlare propagate quite fast is basically where they shine

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding DNS properly but isn't the propagation completely outside of Cloudflare's control? If a local ISP does not update their DNS cache for 15 minutes, Cloudflare can't change that. Cloudflare can control their own DNS zone but can't control individual local ISPs that my clients subscribe from. Or am I confused? The only way this could work is as I said above, if a make new random subdomains that cannot be cached...would that be fast. I don't know if all ISPs worldwide will instantly check the domain origin for an unknown domain name?

Comment: The DNS should obey the TTL, CloudFlare automatic TTL is set to  300 seconds but if required you could set it to less, so in case you had already a domain and set a TTL of 60 seconds, your ISP should give fresh records every 60 seconds, now this happens with all DNS providers not only CloudFlare, the advantage of  CloudFlare is that you get the valid certificates out of the box for all your subdomains and by using their API you could just add your records on demand and expect to be propagated based on the TTL that you defined.

Comment: Hmm. I think you're mistaken. Cloudflare does not have to have for the ISP's TTL to expire since they run their own authoritative DNS system. They claim their internal system can propagate changes worldwide in less than 5 seconds. This might be a real solution. I will investigate further...
https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/

Comment: You have some misunderstandings, I would suggest to just add a domain to CloudFlare or any other DNS provider add couple of subdomains and test check also this about the SOA record: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html

Comment: I have tested this and this is going to work. Using Cloudflare only as a DNS provider (no CDN or SSL needed from them) solves the problem of associating a domain name with a new IP address globally within seconds. They take less then 5 seconds to propagate a DNS update within their network, regardless of a TTL.